# Live-action sci-fi children's / young adult show about a kid who travels through the galaxy with a fast, blue alien

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

There was a live-action kids show in the 2000's about a male child who travels with aliens through the galaxy? One of the aliens was short, blue, and extremely fast. They wore goggles, carried a staff of some sort, and had some sort of frost theme going?

I believe it showed on a public television channel, but I cannot be certain. The name was something along the lines of *Edge of the Galaxy*, or something similar to that. Any info would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Great first question! While we have you, please do check out the [help] and take the [tour]. When you're able, and if it's correct you can mark an answer as correct by clicking the green tick.

Answer (score 11):

I believe this is the 2002 Canadian/American TV series [Galidor: Defenders of the Outer Dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galidor:_Defenders_of_the_Outer_Dimension). It aired on YTV in Canada and Fox Kids in the US.

It follows a young boy and girl traveling the stars with a group of aliens. One of the aliens, named Nepol, is indeed small, blue, wearing goggles and holding a staff-like weapon. Wikipedia says his character "runs at great speed, and can project ice or cold to freeze anything."

[image: Galidor characters]

Comment: It also had a LEGO theme to accompany it, with action figures that could swap parts.